# apache atlas install error in web application

Tags: macos, installation, compiler-errors, apache-atlas

1. [Run command] export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" &&
   mvn clean install

   ````
   [Error message] Running org.apache.atlas.web.adapters.TestEntityREST
   Tests run: 11, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 8, Time elapsed:
   13.995 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.atlas.web.adapters.TestEntityREST enter code here 
   cleanup(org.apache.atlas.web.adapters.TestEntityREST)  Time elapsed:
   0.217 sec  <<< FAILURE!
       java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at org.apache.atlas.RequestContext.clear(RequestContext.java:97)    at
   org.apache.atlas.web.adapters.TestEntityREST.cleanup(TestEntityREST.java:80)
   ...

   [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO]  [INFO] Apache Atlas Server Build
   Tools .................... SUCCESS [  1.489 s] [INFO] apache-atlas
   ....................................... SUCCESS [  8.805 s] [INFO]
   Apache Atlas Integration ........................... SUCCESS [
   42.642 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas Common ................................ SUCCESS [ 14.276 s] [INFO] Apache
   Atlas Typesystem ............................ SUCCESS [01:15 min]
   [INFO] Apache Atlas Client ................................ SUCCESS
   [ 17.168 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas Server API
   ............................ SUCCESS [  8.440 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas
   Notification .......................... SUCCESS [ 38.640 s] [INFO]
   Apache Atlas Graph Database Projects ............... SUCCESS [ 
   0.553 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas Graph Database API .................... SUCCESS [  5.432 s] [INFO] Graph Database Common Code
   ......................... SUCCESS [  5.636 s] [INFO] Shaded version
   of Apache hbase client .............. SUCCESS [ 10.728 s] [INFO]
   Apache Atlas Titan 0.5.4 Graph DB Impl ............. SUCCESS [01:58
   min] [INFO] Apache Atlas Graph Database Implementation Dependencies
   SUCCESS [  0.846 s] [INFO] Shaded version of Apache hbase server
   .............. SUCCESS [ 23.850 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas Repository
   ............................ SUCCESS [13:25 min] [INFO] Apache Atlas
   Authorization ......................... SUCCESS [ 13.707 s] [INFO]
   Apache Atlas Business Catalog ...................... SUCCESS [
   31.334 s] [INFO] Apache Atlas UI .................................... SUCCESS [01:11 min] [INFO]
   Apache Atlas Web Application ....................... FAILURE [04:29
   min] [INFO] Apache Atlas Documentation .........................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas FileSystem Model ......................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Plugin Classloader ....................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Hive Bridge Shim ......................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Hive Bridge ...........................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Falcon Bridge Shim ....................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Falcon Bridge .........................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Sqoop Bridge Shim .....................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Sqoop Bridge ..........................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Storm Bridge Shim .....................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Storm Bridge ..........................
   SKIPPED [INFO] Apache Atlas Distribution ..........................
   SKIPPED [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 26:06 min [INFO] Finished at:
   2017-02-09T01:20:53+09:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 165M/1437M [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
   (default-test) on project atlas-webapp: There are test failures.
   [ERROR]  [ERROR] Please refer to
   /Users/dongkillee/dev/bin/atlas/webapp/target/surefire-reports for
   the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To
   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
   debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1]     
       ```
   ````

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
build with the command [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :atlas-webapp

Answer (score 0):

This is testcase error. Use following command. It will create your build successfully.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" && mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

I have explained the complete solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516481/7310077). briefly, cause it uses some test cases in `maven plugins` in `pom.xml` file, we need to add `-DskipTests` argument when building the Apache Atlas from scratch.

Do the following items to run the project without any error:

1. `git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas`
2. mvn clean install -DskipTests
3. mvn clean package -Pdist -DskipTests