# can't build Apache Atlas

Tags: java, maven, apache-atlas

I'm trying to build Apache Atlas from the [main repository](https://github.com/apache/atlas). As it is described in the `README.md` file, after cloning the repository and changing the current directory to `atlas`, I am trying to build using `mvn clean install` command. Unfortunately, since they closed the issue part of the repository, I will explain my problem here.

**Build Process**

Do the following items in your terminal:

1. `git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas.git`
2. `cd atlas`
3. `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"`
4. `mvn clean install`

After running the last command, I face to the following error:

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 36.2 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.JanusGraphProviderTest
setUp(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.JanusGraphProviderTest)  Time elapsed: 36.136 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.JanusGraphProviderTest.setUp(JanusGraphProviderTest.java:45)

Tests run: 29, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 28, Time elapsed: 37.347 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.GraphQueryTest
createIndices(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.GraphQueryTest)  Time elapsed: 37.236 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AbstractGraphDatabaseTest.createIndices(AbstractGraphDatabaseTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Tests run: 11, Failures: 11, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 347.529 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest
getGetGraphQueryForVertices(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 34.868 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGetGraphQueryForVertices(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:390)

initializationFailureShouldThrowRuntimeException(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.086 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.apache.atlas.AtlasException: startEmbeddedSolr(): failed
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.startEmbeddedSolr(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:294)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.getConfiguration(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:86)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.initializationFailureShouldThrowRuntimeException(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:105)

testAddMultManyPropertyValueTwice(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.065 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testAddMultManyPropertyValueTwice(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:442)

testGetEdges(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.066 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testGetEdges(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:264)

testListProperties(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.063 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testListProperties(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:339)

testMultiplicityOnePropertySupport(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.074 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testMultiplicityOnePropertySupport(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:192)

testMultiplictyManyPropertySupport(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.059 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testMultiplictyManyPropertySupport(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:300)

testPropertyDataTypes(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.05 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testPropertyDataTypes(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:131)

testRemoveEdge(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.055 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveEdge(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:228)

testRemoveProperty(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.052 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveProperty(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:362)

testRemoveVertex(org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest)  Time elapsed: 31.044 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.<init>(SolrException.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.init(ZkTestServer.java:446)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkTestServer.run(ZkTestServer.java:528)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.MiniSolrCloudCluster.<init>(MiniSolrCloudCluster.java:166)
    at org.apache.atlas.runner.LocalSolrRunner.start(LocalSolrRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGraph(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:70)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveVertex(AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.java:250)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.getGetGraphQueryForVertices:390->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.initializationFailureShouldThrowRuntimeException:105 » Atlas
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testAddMultManyPropertyValueTwice:442->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testGetEdges:264->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound Could n...
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testListProperties:339->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound C...
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testMultiplicityOnePropertySupport:192->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testMultiplictyManyPropertySupport:300->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testPropertyDataTypes:131->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveEdge:228->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound Could...
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveProperty:362->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound C...
  AtlasJanusDatabaseTest.testRemoveVertex:250->getGraph:70 » NoClassDefFound Cou...
  GraphQueryTest>AbstractGraphDatabaseTest.createIndices:55 » NoClassDefFound Co...
  JanusGraphProviderTest.setUp:45 » NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class o...

Tests run: 72, Failures: 13, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Atlas Server Build Tools 1.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.735 s]
[INFO] apache-atlas 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........................ SUCCESS [  8.706 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Integration 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SUCCESS [01:52 min]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Test Utility Tools 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [03:24 min]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Common 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [ 21.187 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Client 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [  0.250 s]
[INFO] atlas-client-common 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [  3.927 s]
[INFO] atlas-client-v1 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  6.765 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Server API 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............. SUCCESS [  3.713 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Notification 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [ 46.463 s]
[INFO] atlas-client-v2 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  4.993 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Graph Database Projects 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [  0.292 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Graph Database API 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [ 28.313 s]
[INFO] Graph Database Common Code 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  3.574 s]
[INFO] Apache Atlas JanusGraph-HBase2 Module 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [03:07 min]
[INFO] Apache Atlas JanusGraph DB Impl 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... FAILURE [06:59 min]
[INFO] Apache Atlas Graph Database Implementation Dependencies 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Authorization 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Repository 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas UI 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas New UI 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Web Application 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Documentation 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas FileSystem Model 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Plugin Classloader 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Hive Bridge Shim 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Hive Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Falcon Bridge Shim 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Falcon Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Sqoop Bridge Shim 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Sqoop Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Storm Bridge Shim 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Storm Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Hbase Bridge Shim 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Hbase Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache HBase - Testing Util 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Atlas Kafka Bridge 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-07T01:38:43+03:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project atlas-graphdb-janus: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/user/Desktop/atlas/graphdb/janus/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :atlas-graphdb-janus
```

I don't how to solve the above problem. I would be thankful if someone could help me with janusgraph error.

**P.S:** I need the tar file for hive hook. In order to access that I found out that I have to build the Atlas. Is there any alternative instead of building the project from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the community of Apache Atlas is quite small these days, I want to write the complete story of what has happened and how it works properly, now.

As it seems in the first error trace, the problem is with `maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test`. In the root directory of project (repository) there is a file named `pom.xml` which contains the necessary libraries and frameworks to work with.
It seems that several tests are wrong and because of this problem, the building phase had error. In order to skip tests and not to exit from building process we have to add the `-DskipTests` when we want to build:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

After doing that, I faced to another problem:

> Failed to execute goal on project sqoop-bridge-shim: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.atlas:sqoop-bridge-shim:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.sqoop:sqoop:jar:1.4.7 from/to hortonworks.repo  Transfer failed for https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/sqoop/sqoop/1.4.7/sqoop-1.4.7.jar: repo.hortonworks.com:443 failed to respond

For resolving this error, you can change the version of sqoop which exists in the `pom.xml`. Valid versions can be found in [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop) (Hortonworks tab).

After doing the above steps it has been built successfully and without any error.

[image: building process]

**P.S.** I have seen another possible solution from @khmarbaise comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133708/maven-surefire-plugin2-18-1test-failed) link that proxy may cause the problem.

Useful links:

- [maven plugins error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test)
- [sqoop](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop)

Comment: How do you know which pom file to edit?

Comment: I'm getting an error 
```[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project atlas-distro: Error assembling JAR: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project atlas-distro: Error assembling JAR```